# How to prevent negative result of JodaTime period

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I need to calculate period between two hours in my app which uses JodaTime, here is my code:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
        String s1 = textView9.getText().toString();
        String s2 = textView10.getText().toString();
        final DateTime dateTime1 = format.parseDateTime(s1);
        final DateTime dateTime2 = format.parseDateTime(s2);
        final PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .printZeroAlways()
                .appendHours()
                .appendLiteral("h")
                .appendSeparator(":")
                .printZeroIfSupported()
                .appendMinutes()
                .appendLiteral("min")
                .toFormatter();
        String sum = periodFormatter.print(new Period(dateTime1, dateTime2));
        textView11.setText(sum);
```

So far this code works and displays period, but I noticed that if the `s1` is let say `23:00` and `s2` is time after midnight, let say `19:00` of next day the output of this period will be `-4:00`. Here is my question, does JodaTime have function to easy prevent it or it is some kind of issue that I need to figure out by myself? I was searching for the answer in SO but couldn't find something that can help me. I'm glad for every input answer and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're using the `DateTime` type (which, somewhat obviously, has both a "date" and a "time" component), but you're initializing it with data that only has information about the time of day (your `HH:mm` string).

A better representation of this data would be the `LocalTime` type, which only represents the "time" component.

It sounds like you know for sure that, for each pair of times, one of the following is true:

- If the second time is "after" the first, they're on the same day
- If the second time is "before" the first, the second time is actually on the *next* day

So, here's what I'd do. Change this:

> ```
> final DateTime dateTime1 = format.parseDateTime(s1);
> final DateTime dateTime2 = format.parseDateTime(s2);
> ...
> String sum = periodFormatter.print(new Period(dateTime1, dateTime2));
> ```

to this:

```
LocalTime time1 = format.parseLocalTime(s1);
LocalTime time2 = format.parseLocalTime(s2);
Period period;

if (time1.isBefore(time2)) {
    period = new Period(time1, time2);
} else {
    DateTime dateTime1 = time1.toDateTimeToday();
    DateTime dateTime2 = time2.toDateTimeToday().plusDays(1);
    period = new Period(dateTime1, dateTime2);
}
...
String sum = periodFormatter.print(period);
```

The general outline here:

- Build two `LocalTime` objects so that we're only thinking about time
- If they're "in order", we can compute the period from just the time
- If they're not "in order", turn the first into a "today" date-time and the second into a "tomorrow" date-time, then compute the period

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the period is negative before formatting it. If it is, negate it to get a positive period.

```
Period period = new Period(dateTime1, dateTime2);
if (dateTime1.getMillis() > dateTime2.getMillis()) {
    // 23:00 > 19:00 --> Period = -4:00 + 24:00 = 20:00
    period = period.plusHours(24);
}
String sum = periodFormatter.print(period);
textView11.setText(sum);
```

Disclaimer: I've never used JodaTime, only looked at the documentation but I'm pretty sure this works.

Comment: Ofcourse the output will be `4:00` but what i really need is `20:00`